# JBoss EAP 6 standalone vs domain mode

Tags: jboss, jboss-eap-6

I am trying to decide whether to use standalone or domain mode in our JBoss EAP 6 environments. We have several JBoss environments running on one machine.

What would be the pros and cons? To me, domain model may be an elegant way to manage the environments, but is there a risk that modifying one environment may affect the others? The are in the same xml configuration file...

Standalone would seem easier because configuration files are completely separate. We may have test environments which are configured totally differently from one another.

Does using standalone mode mean that we need to have a separate jboss installation for each environment? Does that impact our licenses in any way? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

A domain environment relevant if you're using the admin tools : CLI, Web Console,... Because all the management task have to be done through the domain controller.

For example, you won't be able to deploy applications by copying in a deployment directory.

Domain mode is really useful if you have several JBoss instances on several server and you want to manage them from a central point. It's even more useful if you have similar instances that you would manage in a server group. For a cluster, for example.

Standalone is better if you want to configure instances by xml, or if you want to use the deployment directory.

Comment: Though configuring a server, even standalone, using CLI, the web console or any management API is the preferred way. Editing the XML you have to ensure the server is stopped and no runtime changes can be made.